# MySQL select all from list where value not in table

Tags: mysql, sql, compare

I cannot create a virtual table for this. Basically what I have, is a list of values:

`'Succinylcholine','Thiamine','Trandate','Tridol Drip'`

I want to know which of those values is not present in `table1` and display them. Is this possible? I have tried using left joins and creating a variable with the list which I can compare to the table, but it returns the wrong results.

This is one of the things I have tried:

```
SET @list="'Amiodarone','Ammonia Inhalents','Aspirin';

SELECT @list FROM table1 where @list not in (
    SELECT Description 
    FROM table1
);
```

Comment: Are you trying to determine whether there are rows whose `Description` columns contain *all* the elements of your list (as substrings)?  Alternatively, are you trying to determine for each element of the list, whether any row's `Description` is (or contains?) that element?

Comment: @JohnBollinger, simply put "find all values from the list that are not in the database. I can't explain it any simpler.

Comment: I'm not looking for "simpler", I'm looking for "more precise".  It would especially be helpful to have some clarity on what "[not] in the database" means.  It would also be helpful to know whether it is essential that your list appear in the query in the form of a single string (as in your example) or whether the query form you can accommodate is more flexible.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I can provide the list in any form or format. Not in the database means just that... check value in the list and see if there is a matching string in the database, if it doesn't output something. I want the items from the list THAT ARE NOT in the database and show those items.

Comment: So that would be the second alternative I suggested: "determine for each element of the list, whether any row's Description is [...] that element" (and return the elements for which the answer is no).  Have you then considered the answer I posted an hour ago?

Comment: Never mind, mine doesn't work.

Comment: Ok, I provided a new answer that should produce the desired result.

Answer (score 3):

With only narrow exceptions, you need to have data in table form to be able to obtain those data in your result set.  This is the essential problem that all attempts at a solution to this problem run into, given that you cannot create a temporary table.  If indeed you can provide the input in *any* form or format (per your comment), then you can provide it in the form of a subquery:

```
(
  SELECT 'Amiodarone' AS description
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Ammonia Inhalents'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Aspirin'
)
```

(Note that that exercises the biggest of the exceptions I noted: you can select scalars directly, without a base table.  If you like, you can express that explicitly -- in MySQL and Oracle, at least -- by selecting `FROM DUAL`.)

In that case, this should work for you:

```
SELECT
  a.description
FROM
  (
    SELECT 'Amiodarone' AS description
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Ammonia Inhalents'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Aspirin'
  ) a
  LEFT JOIN table1
    ON a.description = table1.description
WHERE table1.description IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

That won't work. the variable's contents will be treated as a monolithic string - one solid block of letters, not 3 separate comma-separated values. The query will be parsed/executed as:

```
SELECT ... WHERE "'Amio.....rin'" IN (x,y,z,...)
                 ^--------------^--- string
```

Plus, since you're just doing a sub-select on the very same table, there's no point in this kind of a construct. You could try mysql [`find_in_set()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) function:

```
SELECT @list
FROM table1
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(Description, @list) <> ''
```

Comment: The last part `<> 'not equal to what'` I want the **whole** list to be compared I'm not searching for one single value.

Comment: @user3704920, what do you mean you want to compare the "whole list"?  In the question you say you want to know which values [list elements, yes?] are not present in the table.

Comment: @JohnBollinger yes, I don't understand your above clause as it seems I would have to input a value in there? The reason I have a whole list is so I don't have to compare each value in the list to the database manually.

Comment: Then you should normalize your design and put each of those words into its own childtable/record. Then this becomes a simple `group by/having count(keyword) != 3` query. Don't compensate for bad table design by layering on even worse queries.

Comment: @MarcB thanks for your suggestion but I don't have control over the database.

Comment: then you're stuck with string operations, and loops. mysql has no functions at all for breaking a string into multiple separate records, which is what you'd need for a join/count operation.